# How to re size div from 4 co ordinates using jQuery?

Tags: resize

can any one have any idea how to re size div from 4 co ordinate using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Well, provided that it's already have position:relative you can use:

$('$your_id').left = 123;

$('$your_id').top = 123;

$('$your_id').width = 123;

$('$your_id').height = 123;

Comment: Dear i want to do it by resize event of ui.resize.js, i know the above syntax :)